# perl memory bloat in hash even when doing delete?

Tags: perl, hash, memory-leaks

I've got a long perl script that caches some information from a file
in a hash, and every once in a while (here, every 100000 positions),
it prints the values of the hash for that window, then attempts to
delete most of the contents from the hash, except for a small buffer
to be used in the next iteration.

I say it attempts to delete the contents, because my script blows up
in memory usage, until it uses all memory and crashes. Even though it
seems the delete statement is reducing the number of keys in the hash
(see print STDERR below) to only a small number of elements, the
memory consumption of the script skyrockets as if it is not deleting
the contents. If I comment out the delete statement, it uses the same
amount of memory, with the only difference that it takes longer to
iterate. It seems like the number of keys is reduced after the delete
command, but not the number of values.

I made sure there is no weird buffering with the reading and
outputting of results. In fact, the script doesnt run out of memory if
I just comment out the places where %hash is used, so I narrowed it
down to the filling up and deleting of entries in %hash.

I also tried to use a hashref instead of %hash, and the same is still
happening.

How come it's blowing up in memory? Am I missing anything obvious
here?

```
my %hash;
# while ( Read from input ) {
# Fill hash here and there with: $hash{$this_p}{$this_c}++
# ...
# Then every 100000 entries
 if ( not $pos % 100000 ) {
    print STDERR "pre ", scalar %hash , "\n";
warn total_size(\%hash);
    for my $p ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %hash ) {
        last if ( $p > $max_possible{$subset} );
        if ( $p + $buffer < $pos ) {
            print $out "$p\t";
            for my $c ( keys %{ $hash{$p} } ) {
                print $out "$c ". $hash{$p}{$c} . ";";
            }
            print $out "\n";
            delete $hash{$p};
        }
    }
    print STDERR "post ", scalar %hash , "\n";
warn total_size(\%hash);
  }
#}
```

Output is something like this:

```
pre 322484/524288
134297952 at /home/
post 681/524288
4368924 at /home/av
pre 681/524288
4368924 at /home/av
post 681/524288
4368924 at /home/av
pre 681/524288
4368924 at /home/av
post 681/524288
4368924 at /home/av
pre 629257/1048576
260016542 at /home/
post 344/1048576
8477509 at /home/av
pre 1903885/4194304
689633878 at /home/
post 900/4194304
33790436 at /home/a
[...]
```

This is using perl v5.14.2 on a 64bit Linux box.

Comment: When you delete elements of a hash, it seems the allocated buckets are not reset. `perl -le'$min = 0; $max = shift; %a = map $_ => 1, $min ..$max; for (1 .. $max - 10) { delete $a{$_} }; print scalar %a' 1000001` Output: `5/524288`  Try copying the key/values instead.

Comment: @TLP copying the key/values?

Comment: create a new hash by copying the old one, and let the old one go out of scope

Comment: @001193871937819863213487938912 If your keys are numeric, you might consider using an array instead. That would also remove the need for sorting.

Comment: Don't forget that the memory previously allocated to the hash will not be returned to the O/S; it will just be part of the pool of memory available for (re)use by Perl.  That means that the visible memory use will not decrease.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, after the delete statement, shouldn't the memory be reused straight-away when I add new elements to the hash? It's not the case.

Comment: Usually, yes — you'd expect the memory to be reused.  However, Perl does also have some memory management for the various types of data, and it may be that your hash is confusing that (so that the memory isn't considered reusable yet — a cycle in the memory refs in a garbage collection scheme).  I don't know exactly what's going on — I've not studied your code.  I'm just raising a warning flag that it isn't as simple as 'deleting the elements of a hash will make the memory go away'.

Comment: @ikegami, I changed it now, it seems delete is doing its thing, but then the size goes up again when new key/value pairs are added.

Comment: Can you provide less ambiguous evidence that you are actually deleting?  We don't see what's printed to `$out`, and we don't know `$p` nor the `$max{subset}` limit, etc..  Can you insert a warning right before the deletion?  `scalar(%h)` doesn't speak directly to the number of elements.  Can you show us `scalar(keys(%hash))` (or `0+keys(%h)`) instead to confirm that elements are being deleted?

Comment: Show us some example data.

Comment: Why is Perl designed this way ? Why not release the unused memory back to OS ? And ask for it again when Perl needs it ?

Comment: @Jean, I agree with your observation that it does not seem to be releasing the memory back. Is this documented somewhere that hash or hashrefs behave in this manner in Perl?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number of elements you place in the hash in each pass is growing as your program runs. `0+keys(%hash)` would tell you the exact number, but the numerator in the following will be similar (but lower)

```
                      322484 added
pre  322484/524288
                      321803 cleared (99.8% of added)
post    681/524288
                           0 added
pre     681/524288
                           0 cleared (100.0% of added)
post    681/524288
                           0 added
pre     681/524288
                           0 cleared (100.0% of added)
post    681/524288
                      628576 added
pre  629257/1048576
                      628913 cleared (100.0% of added)
post    344/1048576
                     1903541 added
pre 1903885/4194304
                     1902641 cleared (100.0% of added)
post    900/4194304
```

The denominator is only growing because the numerator is growing. It's not relevant. It's not cumulative growth. It would get that big even if you had a fresh hash every time.

The numerator is only growing because the number of elements you add to the hash grows. As you can see, the clearing code works extremely well.

This doesn't look like a memory leak at all; it looks like you're actually using the memory. Maybe you should clear it more often?

Instead of

```
if (not $pos % 100000) {
    ...
}
```

use

```
if (keys(%hash) >= 1_000_000) {
    ...
}
```

Or if you want regular feedback,

```
if (++$since_last >= 100_000 || keys(%hash) >= 1_000_000) {
    $since_last = 0;
    ...
}
```

Adjust the limits as required.